# 'QuerySet' object has no attribute '_meta'

Tags: python, django-views, django-class-based-views

i am developing a simple app with python django framework and i am using Class based Views, when i use the UpdateView and try to run my template i get this error;

```
'QuerySet' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

This is my view codes

```
class UpdateStaff(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    template_name = 'app/update_staff.html'
    form_class = UpdateStaffForm
    model = Staff

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        obj = Staff.objects.filter(pk=self.kwargs['staff_id'])
        return obj

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST or None, 
                               instance=self.get_object())
        if form.is_valid():
            obj = form.save(commit=False)
            obj.save()
            messages.success(self.request, "Staff has been updated")
            return self.get_success_url()
        else:
            messages.error(self.request, "Staff not updated")
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('update_staff'))

    def get_success_url(self):
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('manage_staffs'))

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(UpdateStaff,         
                        self).get_context_data()
        context['messages'] = messages.get_messages(self.request)
        context['form'] = self.form_class(self.request.POST or None, 
                                          instance=self.get_object())
        return context
```

and this is my form codes:

```
class UpdateStaffForm(ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = Staff
    exclude = (
        'profile_picture', 'start_work', 'last_login', 'groups', 
        'user_permissions', 'is_active', 'is_superuser',
        'date_joined', 'end_work', 'can_sell_out_of_assigned_area', 
        'is_staff')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UpdateStaffForm, self).__init__(*args, 
                                                     **kwargs)
        for field_name, field in self.fields.items():
            field.widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
```

Anyone having an idea to solve this please help.

Comment: Please reformat your code first, the indent is not correct, so the code is hard to read.

Comment: @MenglongLi How can i do that

Comment: @JosephDaudi No traceback?

Comment: @MenglongLi approved your edit suggestion

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The `get_object` method returns `queryset` i.e list of records, instead of `instance`.To get `instance` you can use `first()` on `filter()` . This will gives you first occurrence.

```
def get_object(self, queryset=None):
    obj = Staff.objects.filter(pk=self.kwargs['staff_id']).first()
    return obj
```

Comment: Thank you, that first() did it!

Comment: How can i do this for multi objects?

Comment: I run into a similar problem, as .first() is not working for a queryset with multiple objects

Answer (score 2):

Late answer but worth it.

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
...
def get_object(self, queryset=None):
    obj = get_object_or_404(Staff, pk=self.kwargs['staff_id'])
    return obj
```

This approach will return `HTTP 404 Not Found` response if object not found.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe solve someone problem:

```
def get_object(self, queryset=None):
    obj, created = Person.objects.get_or_create(
        first_name='John',
        last_name='Lennon',
        defaults={'birthday': date(1940, 10, 9)},
    )    
    return obj
```